# Suppress Inspections for specific Debug class in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

One of the developers in my team likes to leave Logs in the code constantly. We recently switched to using a debug class to allow us to switch these flows / batches of messages on and off like follows

```
public class Dbg {
    public static final boolean LOG_FLOW_DEEPLINKS = false;
    public static final boolean LOG_FLOW_IMAGES = true;
    public static final boolean LOG_FLOW_BLOGGER = false;
}
```

and used like

```
if (Dbg.LOG_FLOW_DEEPLINKS || Dbg.LOG_FLOW_IMAGES ) Log.v(TAG, ...);
```

This is good because it gets compiled out completely, the problem is Android Studio is highlighting every one of the usage statements for simplification to (bool).

We want to keep the "...can be simplified to ..." inspections as they help the junior developers, but the amount of things highlighted is distracting. Is there a way through annotations (or other means) to suppress the inspections relating to Dbg across the whole project?

Ive looked [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/suppressing-inspections.html#1) but it wasnt much help as it doesn't tell me what annotations are available

Comment: Move your actual logging code into `Dbg` itself (`Dbg.v(TAG, ...);`), so you only have the `if` test in one place.

Comment: But then it doesnt get compiled out, so there is the overhead of dozens of calls to that method

Comment: That overhead is measured in microseconds, unless you are doing something silly, like logging in a tight loop.

Comment: Yes, he does a lot of that. He also logs every method accessed. I've removed a lot of it, but he always adds it back in, so this was my compromise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Boolean.parseBoolean()` will do the trick:

```
public class Dbg {
    public static final boolean LOG_FLOW_DEEPLINKS = Boolean.parseBoolean("false");
    public static final boolean LOG_FLOW_IMAGES = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
    public static final boolean LOG_FLOW_BLOGGER = Boolean.parseBoolean("false");
}
```

BTW: This is also done in the automatically generated `<yourPackage>.BuildConfig.java` file so it is an "official" way to solve the warnings

Comment: I was hoping there was a hack-free way but this is very simple and works, thanks!